# Changing icon of a mounted disk image

Tags: macos, icon, mount, dmg

I want to modify the icon of my mounted disk image, the same way as `FUSE for OS X`.

My desktop screenshot, where my disk image is the left one (name is censored):

[image: Dekstop]

Changing the icon of the `dmg` is simple, but has no effect on the mounted drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The, e.g., osxfuse-2.8.2.dmg disk image file uses a hidden **.icns** file named **.VolumeIcon.icns** in the root of the volume and has the Custom Icon attribute set, probably using `/usr/bin/SetFile`. E.g.: `SetFile -a C /Volumes/FUSE\ for\ OS\ X`

You can also change the icon of the mounted disk image from its Info sheet. Place the wanted icon on the Clipboard then select the disk image on the Desktop and press Command-I then click the icon in the upper-left corner of the Info sheet and paste the wanted image there.

Answer (score 2):

To add a custom icon to the mounted volume of your dmg file, you first have to convert it to a sparsebundle or at least to a r/w dmg:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDSB -o /path/to/output/image /path/to/source/image.dmg #the extension sparsebundle will be added to the output file automatically
```

Then double-click the sparsebundle to mount it as a volume.

Copy the custom icon. Then <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> the **mounted volume**.
Highlight the icon in the upper-left corner of the Info window and paste the icon (in the clipboard) with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Unmount the volume and convert to its previous type.

Comment: You **do not** have to first convert it to a sparse bundle!  Also the OP specifically said "_I want to modify the icon of my mounted disk image, the same way as FUSE for OS X_" and converting to a sparse bundle and using cmd+I is not how it's done.  Although I had also given the cmd+I method as an alternative.

Comment: @user3439894 It has to be r/w at least. If the icon is big the empty space on the mounted might not be sufficient. Therefore I suggested a sparsebundle

Comment: Yes of course the .dmg file needs to be R/W to be modified, that goes without saying, however as I previously said it doesn't first have to be converted to a sparse bundle.  Additionally an appropriate .icns file is going to be relatively small, probably less then 512 KB so unless the image file is already full it shouldn't be an issue.  If the .dmg is UDRO is can be converted to UDRW without UDSB.